# $_SESSION empty after redirecting back from external site despite resuming with the same ID based on cookie

Tags: php, session

I have one script that saves data received from a form in session and then sends a request to an external site. The site then redirects to a thank you page on the same server as the first script. `session_start()` on the thank you page returns true and `session_id()` returns the same ID as in the first script but the $_SESSION array is empty.

index.php

```
<?php
session_start();

if ($_GET['submit-payment'] ?? false) {
    if (($_POST['CREDIT_ACCT_CODE'] ?? false) && ($_POST['AMT'] ?? false)) {
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
        }
        // if I dump $_SESSION here all the data is there
        session_write_close();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head></head>
    <body onload="submit();">
        <form action="<URL TO EXTERNAL SITE>" method="post" name="paymentForm">
            <input type="hidden" name="UPAY_SITE_ID" value="3" />
            <input type="hidden" name="CREDIT_ACCT_CODE" value="<?= $_POST['CREDIT_ACCT_CODE'] ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="<?= $_POST['AMT'] ?>" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function submit() {
        console.log('<?= session_id() ?>');
        document.paymentForm.submit();
    }
</script>

<?php
    } else {
        throw new Exception('CREDIT_ACCT_CODE or AMT parameter missing from POST data, could not submit payment form');
    }
die;
}

?>
```

thankyou.php

```
<?php
session_start();
var_dump(session_id(), $_SESSION, $_COOKIE);
//session ID is the same as the one logged in index.php, $_SESSION is an empty array and $_COOKIE contains a PHPSESSID cookie with the ID
?>
```

Here is the session cookie data:

```
PHPSESSID:"<SESSION ID>"
Created:"Thu, 26 May 2022 07:40:58 GMT"
Domain:"<DOMAIN>"
Expires / Max-Age:"Session"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:false
Last Accessed:"Thu, 26 May 2022 10:53:44 GMT"
Path:"/"
SameSite:"None"
Secure:false
Size:41
```

php -i output for sessions:

```
Session Support => enabled
Registered save handlers => files user
Registered serializer handlers => php_serialize php php_binary wddx

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
session.auto_start => Off => Off
session.cache_expire => 180 => 180
session.cache_limiter => nocache => nocache
session.cookie_domain => no value => no value
session.cookie_httponly => no value => no value
session.cookie_lifetime => 0 => 0
session.cookie_path => / => /
session.cookie_secure => 0 => 0
session.gc_divisor => 1000 => 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime => 1440 => 1440
session.gc_probability => 1 => 1
session.lazy_write => On => On
session.name => PHPSESSID => PHPSESSID
session.referer_check => no value => no value
session.save_handler => files => files
session.save_path => no value => no value
session.serialize_handler => php => php
session.sid_bits_per_character => 4 => 4
session.sid_length => 32 => 32
session.upload_progress.cleanup => On => On
session.upload_progress.enabled => On => On
session.upload_progress.freq => 1% => 1%
session.upload_progress.min_freq => 1 => 1
session.upload_progress.name => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => PHP_SESSION_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
session.upload_progress.prefix => upload_progress_ => upload_progress_
session.use_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_only_cookies => 1 => 1
session.use_strict_mode => 0 => 0
session.use_trans_sid => 0 => 0
```

The session resumes with the same ID but no session data is present.

Comment: If you remove the `session_write_close();`, then is your `$_SESSION` having proper values?

Comment: @LajosArpad no, it's an empty array as well

Comment: Are the two pages of the same domain?

Comment: Can you give cookie details from the console?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, they're on the same domain but different subpages

Comment: @JoelCrypto I edited the question to contain cookie data

Comment: Are you using Apache?

Comment: @LajosArpad Yes, it's Apache

Comment: @matru can you share the exact URLs of each page?

Comment: @LajosArpad
https://stage.domain.com/forms/form/index.php and https://stage.domain.com/payment-success/index.php

Comment: It is highly probable that you have different paths in the different cookies: https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path. It defaults to /. So you will need to set the proper path for the cookie. Let me know if you are successful in doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Using your code (without the redirection to an external site), I don't have any problem on my server (Apache 2.4, PHP 8.1.5).
Maybe the redirection from the website looks like CSRF to your browser and therefore is blocked in a way.
Does it work without an redirection ?

Comment: Without redirection it works fine

Comment: This means the browser, php or something is blocking the session. Sounds strange however that you do have the session_id. Maybe it is the strict mode (session)?

Comment: Strict mode is off, I've added configuration info to the question

Comment: @Lajos might be right, try to change domain to stage.domain.com (in php.ini config).